# isExternalStorageLegacy is false when update android system from 10 to 11

Tags: scope, storage, android-11, scoped-storage

On my project manifest file

```
    android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

we have a migration scenario for scope  storage. we are using legacy storage on android 10 but we want to migrate when version updated to 11.

we have install app on a android 10 device. Later we have updated to android system 11.
when we launch app `Environment.isExternalStorageLegacy()`

return **false**

android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage is true but return false . do you have any reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Because Android 11 does not accept legacy storage as seen below. System is ignore your `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` field.

> Caution: After you update your app to target Android 11 (API level
> 30), the system ignores the requestLegacyExternalStorage attribute
> when your app is running on Android 11 devices, so your app must be
> ready to support scoped storage and to migrate app data for users on
> those devices. [Android Data Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases)

Comment: I know this but ı need to migrate my files to scoped storage and I have read that android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage this flag activate legacyStorage on android 11. I have tried 2 case; first case ı have installed my  app (target 10) on android 11 after that ı have upgraded it to new apk (target 11 with preserve flag) and legacystorage is active. but in second case ı have install my app (target 10) on android 10 device later ı have upgraded  new version (app with target 11) then ı have update system to 11 ı need a migrate my files but preserver flag not affect